# How to make JPG load only on hover?

Tags: css, browser, loading

Is it possible to make a browser load JPG image only on hover (CSS) without **any** JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of, if there is no `background-url` in the default state and then there is a `background-url` in the `:hover` state then it works, and it actually downloads when the `:hover` is initiated, not before. But you still don't get it's `height` & `width` values before hand without javascript unless you know them.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p89uczxs/)

Comment: that's no a problem, they are stored on the server. many thanks.

Comment: do you know if it is the default behaviour in all browsers? I don't really want to add 10MB worth of pictures on a page and have them being downloaded in some IE8.

Comment: not sure about IE, seems to work the same way across the latest Safari, FF & Chrome. I'm guessing IExx does something stupid though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background: url(myimagelocation/myimage.jpg)` on the hover pseudo-selector.

Example.

```
.mybox {
<!-- make sure you allow enough spatial dimensions here. -->
}
.mybox:hover {
 background: url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
}
```